# Trouble installing ROS Noetic Ninjemys on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting following error, please help:--

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgazebo11 amd64 11.0.0-2~focal                                                                                                                
  Connection failed [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gazebo11/libgazebo11_11.0.0-2~focal_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358404/trouble-installing-ros-noetic-ninjemys-on-ubuntu-20.04/) by [Aakashp](https://answers.ros.org/users/57188/aakashp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the first thing I would do is make sure that your Ubuntu repositories are configured to allow "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse.". You can find the information for this over here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

And as the error message suggests, you could try to update your Debian package by using `sudo apt update` in the terminal. After that, you could try to install the full desktop version of Ros with this command in the terminal: `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full`.

This worked for me, hopefully for you as well (:

---

Originally posted by [MaxM](https://answers.ros.org/users/56385/maxm/) with karma: 20 on 2020-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aakashp](https://answers.ros.org/users/57188/aakashp/) on 2020-07-31**:
Hi, Ubuntu is already configured to allow restricted, universe and multiverse.
I had also executed "sudo apt update" but it didn't help.
Also, I am trying to install full desktop version only.

**Comment by [MaxM](https://answers.ros.org/users/56385/maxm/) on 2020-07-31**:
Did you try everything else that they specify in http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu?

**Comment by [Aakashp](https://answers.ros.org/users/57188/aakashp/) on 2020-10-26**:
Yes @MaxM, I had followed the instructions line by line.